# communicate between 2 different controllers

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app where we have 4 different pages.Each page has its own controller. There is an home page which has a controller which routes to each page and its controller using

```
when('/a',{
            templateUrl: './components/a.html',
            controller:'aCtrl'
    }).
when('/b',{
            templateUrl: './components/b.html',
            controller:'bCtrl'
    }).
when('/c',{
            templateUrl: './components/c.html',
            controller:'cCtrl'
    }).
when('/d',{
            templateUrl: './components/d.html',
            controller:'dCtrl'
    }).
when('/home',{
            templateUrl: './components/Home.html',
            controller:homeCtrl'
}).
```

Now I want to share some data or some common functions between these controllers/pages. How can we do this? I googled it they say to use SERVICE. But I don't know in which controller I need to write the service. Can anybody give a good example for this.

Answer (score 2):

A service in AngularJS is not written *within* a controller. It is bound to your app directly and can be used anywhere within your application. This is why Services are the recommended means of communication between controllers in AngularJS.

What you need to do is write a service like so:

`angular.module('yourApp').service('serviceName', function () {....});`

Within the service, you can:

- Fetch data from an API end point (You can use the `$http` provider for this)
- Define constant data (You can use Angular's `constant` provider for this)
- Define some code that takes in some data and manipulates it and returns new data
- Pretty much anything else you want to do with your data

Now, include the service in your controller as a dependency like so:

```
angular.module('yourApp').controller('yourController', function (serviceName) {
  console.log(serviceName.getData());
  // Do something with your data
});
```

Now within this controller, you have access to the data that the service has returned. Of course, the same service can be injected into multiple controllers, thereby making it possible to share data across controllers.

Comment: ok. I have added a sServ.js which has angular.module('myApp').service('sServ', ['$resource','$scope','usSpinnerService',function($resource,$scope,usSpinnerService){$scope.test = function(){} }]);                                                                                                             Now in my controller1,var app= angular.module('GMod',[ 'ivh.treeview', 'angularSpinner' ]);geoOccApp.controller('gModCtrl',[ 'sServ',  function(sServ) {     //how can i call routeChangeStart or startSpin or any other function  } ]);  It is giving me an error

Comment: Where does `startSpin` exist? If you want to call something within the service, you need to first defined it as `this.startSpin` within the service body, and then use it as `sServ.startSpin` within your controller

Comment: startSpin exists in services 'sServ'

Comment: In that case, you can use it like I've mentioned, after first injecting it into the controller and then calling `sServ.startSpin`

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can share data.

1. event
2. services
3. $rootScope

Services provide an easy way for us to share data and functionality throughout our app. The services we create are singletons that can be injected into controllers and other services, making them the ideal place for writing reusable code.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('leftCtrl', function ($scope,userService) {
left.btnClicked = function (object) {
   userService.saveData(object);
}
});

app.controller('rightCtrl', function ($scope, userService) {
$scope.getData = userService.getData();
});

app.service('userService', function () {
   var data = {};
   this.saveData = function(object){
   data = object;
}

this.getData = function(){
return data;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Dustin has the right approach. However there are times when you could use a different approach and that is to wrap the application in an AppController.

Everything that is in AppController can now be accessed. You could use this approach to put functions or constants that you want the child controllers of the application to have access to and don't have to inject services everywhere.

```
<body ng-controller="AppController">
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```